# VBA working with range across multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, range, worksheet

I've came across a problem when working with ranges on different worksheets within the same workbook. Let me demonstrate you this on a simple example:

We have two worksheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2. Each has range A1:A3 with some values. After running below code excel is giving me an error *1004 method range of object _worksheet failed*

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

Comment: `Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1", ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown))` etc.

Comment: ah it was that simple! Thanks